# Storing array values in he database using php?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to create an php script which can read and array list from android and read it's element and store it in data base, now I have been able to store the data in an text file but unable to proceed further, could some body help me out in this matter?
this is the php script which I have used:-

```
<?php
$i=0;
$password="";
$user="root";
$database="shadowpets";
$host="localhost";
$response=array();
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database)or die("Unable to connect");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

    if(isset($_POST['OrderSummary'])){

        $data=$_POST['OrderSummary'];
        $file='text.txt';
         $result=file_put_contents($file,$data);  

            $response["success"]=1;
            $response["message"]="done";
    }else{
        $response["success"]=0;
        $response["message"]="parameters not correctly formatted";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
    ?>
```

what changes I can do here, so I can read the data store it in the database?

Comment: you can use serialize()

Comment: You should create `INSERT` sql statement.

Comment: What you mean by _i want to read the data stored in the ['OrderSummary']_ what data are you putting in there. You need to show how and what data fields you send to your `PHP`.

Comment: i'm sending an arraylist and i want to read the elements of the arraylist and store it i the database

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set up a database and a table in a database server (MySQL).

Then you can create an insert statement like below, bind its parameters and execute it.

```
if (!($statement = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO `your_table` (`OrderSummary`) VALUES (?)'))) {
    die('Could not prepare statement: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);
}
if (!$statement->bind_param('s', $_POST['OrderSummary'])) {
    die('Could not bind parameter: (' . $statement->errno . ') ' . $statement->error);
}
if (!$statement->execute()) {
    die('Could not execute statement: (' . $statement->errno . ') ' . $statement->error);
}
```

Comment: i know i want to read the ['OrderSummary'] elements and store it in the database

Comment: OrderSummary is just a string value. You can just echo it and then execute insert statement (like above) to put in in the right field of your database. If OrderSummary is an array give us the output of the array to see the fields and also the structure of the your db.

Comment: iam not able to parse the string value